# Drop a list of rows from Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a loop to get a list of rows to drop.

```
cols = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i != len(df)-1:
        if (df['Player'][i] == df['Player'][i+1]):
            cols.append(i+1)
```

Now I want to go through cols and drop each row by its number. I've tried using the following loop to drop these rows but it's not working.

```
for col in cols:
    df.drop([[col]])
```

Comment: By default, `df.drop()` returns a dataframe, rather than modifying it in place; supplying an `inplace = True` argument should make your code work the way you want it to. But there is a better way to do this; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dropping rows:

```
df.drop(rows,inplace=True)
```

For dropping columns:

```
df.drop(cols,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,3,4,5]})
print('DataFrame with initialised :\n',df,'\n')
df.drop([2,4],inplace=True)
print('DataFrame after dropping 2 rows:\n',df,'\n')
df.drop(['B'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print('DataFrame after dropping 1 column:\n',df,'\n')
```

Output:

```
DataFrame with initialised :
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  5  5 

DataFrame after dropping 2 rows:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
3  4  4 

DataFrame after dropping 1 column:
   A
0  1
1  2
3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to delete rows with duplicated value in col 'Player', you can:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Player'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants to drop dups only! Good call.

Comment: This is probably not the case though; it looks like OP only wants to drop rows immediately preceded by a duplicate value of `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get rid of rows preceded by a duplicate value of `Player`. With `pandas`, always try to work with vectorization: `df.Player == df.Player.shift()` checks whether each entry in `Player` is equal to the last, so a one-line solution is

```
df[df.Player != df.Player.shift()]
```